# Помогите откорректировать селектор запрос для AngleSharp

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Только начал изучать парсинг сайтов при помощи AngleSharp. для начала поставил задачу собрать все картинки с сайта lol.reactor.cc (а именно с первого поста). выстроил такой код и такой запрос

```
        var cellSelector = @"#background #container #page #pageinner div.PdtfVTUDBsXi #contentinner #post_list #postContainer4810585 div.post_top div.post_content div.image a";
        var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
        string[] im = cells.Select(el => el.GetAttribute("href")).ToArray();
```

как я смог найти # обозначает id, div.something это div class="something" и пробел - потомок. если я в чем то ошибся - подскажите. ну и программа в итоге выдает пустой список строк. подскажите в чем проблема и как это исправить. палками не бейте я только пытаюсь разобраться.

вот весь код:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==ConsoleApp2==");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var parser = new Parser();
        var ress = parser.GetWiki().Result;
        foreach(var i in ress.Images)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

class Parser
{
    public async Task<WikiInfo> GetWiki()
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        var address = "http://lol.reactor.cc/";
        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
        WikiInfo result = new WikiInfo();
        var cellSelector = @"#background #container #page #pageinner div.PdtfVTUDBsXi #contentinner #post_list #postContainer4810585 div.post_top div.post_content div.image a";
        var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
        string[] im = cells.Select(el => el.GetAttribute("href")).ToArray();
        result.Images = im;
        return result;
    }
}

public class WikiInfo
{
    public string[] Images { get; set; } = new string[300];
}
```

Comment: Вы собираете не img, но a элементы - посмотрите на своё условие. Я бы собирал так, вполне достаточно: `div.post_content  img.image` (не пробовал, под рукой нет студии) И вообще, вы когда писали код - настолько жёстко прибили условие излишним количеством "гвоздей" (элементов которые указали), что условие сложнее корректировать при различных редизайнах сайта, когда они случатся.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. упростил запрос и все стало работать